# Subform requery error?

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub ProjectSearchBtn_MouseUp(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    [ProjectQSubF].Requery
End Sub
```

Above is the code in one of my buttons. When I push said button (ProjectSearchBtn) it gives me a

"Rune-time error '2465':
Microsoft Access can't find the field '|1' referred to in your expression.

What is wrong? I am quite confused, as this exact code (except changed button name + subform name) works elsewhere perfectly fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this line throws an error ...

```vb
[ProjectQSubF].Requery
```

... the reason might be that *ProjectQSubF* is the name of a form which is contained in a subform control.

If that is the case, Access will not recognize that name in this context.  Instead, use the name of the subform *control* which contains that form.  For example, if the name of the subform control is *MySubForm*, use one of these 2 alternatives ...

```vb
Me!MySubForm.Requery
Me!MySubForm.Form.Requery
```

You will need to identify the name of the subform control and substitute that for *MySubForm*.